# POSIX or Linux way of getting unique ID of shell process

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, persistence, posix

I'm writing a simple command-line utility program and would would like to be able to get some kind of globally unique identifier for the parent process (i.e. the shell in which the command is run).

PID is not enough for me, because over time there is a possibility that two PID values will collide.

My use case is as follows: I want to store "session" data from running the command-line utility that persists across all instances of the utility that are run within the same shell process. I don't want this data shared with other shell instances. I want some kind of identifier that will allow me to perform that association without the possibility of collision.

I've ruled out PID and PID+tty. What would be nice would be a way to query process start date/time so my unique ID would be PID+tty+start date/time...

Any ideas gratefully accepted!

Comment: Could you get something at least close to the start time from looking at the timestamp on `/proc/<pid>` or `/proc/<pid>/stat` or something like that?

Comment: @Eric Renouf, good idea. In theory that would work on Linux, but would it be portable to POSIX OSes generally?

Answer (score 3):

## Unique Files

I recommend to use a file-based approach. Unique files, especially unique temporary files, are needed in many situations, so you can use a tool for exactly this purpose, mktemp:

```
$ mktemp -t identifier.XXXXXXXXXX
/tmp/identifier.yaJMl0cBnK
```

If you execute this command in your parent shell, you will get a name of a newly created file, created in a guaranteed unique manner. As you can see, the suffix of X's (at least 3) is replaced with random content, so if the target file is already in use, mktemp has many chances to create an alternative.

To avoid pollution, make sure that your parent shell removes the file when your work is done.

Now you can either write the date/time into the file or adjust the identifier part. It really depends on what you like more.

## Unique Sessions

As figured out in comments, the creation of a temporary file is not always desired. In fact, the use of mktemp cannot be considered POSIX-compliant, because the utility mktemp(1) is not covered in the standard.

Another approach would be the utilization of the "session id" (technically correct: "process id of the session leader"). The question specifically states that the parent process is a shell. Shells become session leaders in order to manage their process groups. You can see the session id by calling ps with -o session, e.g. `ps -o pid,session,cmd`.

The session id remains as long as at least one process is still inside that session. You can safely assume that the session id is unique to your group of programs and unique on your system. This is also true if the parent shell terminates. Your programs become orphaned, but remain in their session. The session is only destroyed (and session id released) if the last program terminates.

In C/C++, you can retrieve the session id of your process by calling `getsid(0)`, which is covered by POSIX.

Comment: that's clever. However, I want my command-line utility program to be standalone, so it shouldn't have to depend on me running `$ mktemp` in the shell. Can you think of a way I can write code within the command-line utility (child process) so that this works? I think the main difficulty would be how to make the parent process (shell) responsible for deleting a temp file created by the child...

Comment: How do you want your programs to behave when the parent process terminates? Are they background jobs that continue running or are they supposed to terminate, too?

Comment: your edits are great, very helpful as well. However, what about persistence across reboots? I imagine session IDs issued after a reboot can collide as well...?

Comment: to answer your question my child processes only last for an instant at a time. Think of something like the `ls` or `cd` utilities.

Comment: If you want to keep these across reboots, you probably don't want to delete the files created with mktemp. The issue in your first comment (cleaning up) does not exist then. Export the file name in an environment variable and let your programs read it through getenv, being POSIX-compatible. If you don't want files: What are these identifiers good for that you have such a requirement?

Comment: I don't want to keep state across reboots -- I want to avoid unique ID collisions across reboots ... because I might have to lazily delete my "sesssion" files...

Comment: To avoid leftover temporary files (after all the state is unimportant), just make sure that you use a ramdisk mount. /tmp is most of the times a good candidate already. No files after reboot, no collisions.

Comment: @0xbe5077ed the session ID numbers are not unique not only across reboots but also when the PID wraps back to 1 (for Linux usually at 32768 but the wrap value can be changed). Did you manage to resolve the problem? I think you need to get the process or session start time somehow.